# how fixed this (error after imp from csv)?

Tags: python, pandas

after search on csv

im try calculating operation in row :

```
import csv
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import operator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv('data-02.csv')
Space1 = "********************"
with open('data-02.csv', 'r+') as data:
    base = csv.reader(data)
    ticker = input('Entre a Ticker: ')
    for row in base:
        if row[2] == ticker:
            print(row)

            if df["price"] > df["lowPrice"] and df["price"] < df["highPrice"]:
               print("Wait More Range ")
            elif df["price"] < df["lowPrice"]:
               print("TREND DOWN Now ")
               print(Space1)

            else:
               print("TREND UP Now ")
               print(Space1)
```

> from fist line to 15 everything is ok , but after that i want calculating inside this `row`

im get this error :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnTlz.png)

[data on excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mzeN.png)

Comment: What does your data look like? Which line throws the error? Please [edit] to provide more details, including a full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to iterate both on "df" and "base" rows?
If so, you have to slice the "df" to get the value for the columns at the row (using iloc - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html - or loc - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

The comparisons on the if and elif conditions returns Series, not a single boolean. If you absolutely have to take this approach on having both "df" and "base", I'd sugest:

```
for idx,row in enumerate(base):
    if row[2] == ticker:
        print(row)

        if df.loc[idx,"price"] > df.loc[idx,"lowPrice"] and df.loc[idx,"price"] < df.loc[idx,"highPrice"]:
           print("Wait More Range ")
        elif df.loc[idx,"price"] < df.loc[idx,"lowPrice"]:
           print("TREND DOWN Now ")
           print(Space1)

        else:
           print("TREND UP Now ")
           print(Space1)
```

Comment: thank you sir ,, im replace your code but i see this ; NameError: name 'idx' is not defined 
look img : 
https://imgur.com/a/fBjhhug

Comment: yes sir "row" inside "base"   
base = csv

Comment: Did you replace the "for" statement as well?

Comment: im forget LOL .. its working now .. sir thank you very help full ♥

Comment: sir .. please can you help me with this issue ? after select my row target ex: 53  after run show me row 54 ? i want 53 not 54 .. how can select my target ? why +1 ?

Comment: The first row in "base" might be the table header, while in "df" it is the first row of content. If not specified, while reading a csv as dataframe, the first row acts as a header (naming the columns). Try replacing idx for idx -1 below the "for" statement. Consider, for your application, using only the "base" or the "df", not both

Comment: ok sir ... im try now

Comment: like that ? :  for idx -1, row in enumerate(base):

Comment: its working sir ..Thank you so much...... you are genius sir ♥♥♥